# Many to One Hibernate Java

Tags: java, hibernate

Eu tenho 2 entidades:

> Contratos, que possui apenas id, numero
>
> Aditivo, que possui id, numero, contrato

O contrato do aditivo é uma chave estrangeira, no banco de dados está funcionando certinho

funciona assim:
1 contrato pode ter vários aditivos e
1 aditivo pertence a apenas 1 contrato

Eu quero ao buscar um contrato, ele me trazer a lista de todos os aditivos relacionados aquele contrato, então pra modelar eu fiz assim

```
Classe Aditivo:
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(length = 300)
private String numero;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="contrato", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Contrato contrato;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Aditivo [id=" + id + ", numero=" + numero + ", contrato="
            + contrato + "]";
}

Classe Contrato:
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(length = 300)
private String numero;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="contrato",fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT) 
private List<Aditivo> aditivo;

@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contratos [id=" + id + ", aditivo=" + aditivo + ", numero="
                + numero + "]";
    }
```

Só que quando eu vou dar um `getContratos`, ele me dá um `StackOverflowError`
nesse erro ele diz muita coisa, vou colocar algumas linhas:

> java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
>     model.Aditivo.toString(Aditivo.java:96)
>     java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(Unknown Source)
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:501)
>
> java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
>     model.Contratos.toString(Contratos.java:491)
>     java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source) ...

Comment: Você sobrescreveu o ToString?

Comment: sim, sobrescrevi agora o tostring e o hashcode e equals agora e continua o  mesmo erro

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta e colocar como está seu toString e também colocar como vc está fazendo o `getContratos()`?

Comment: editei, o tostring eu fiz automaticamente, no getcontratos, eu tenho no ContratosMB um getlista que funciona normalmente, só me acusa o erro de stackoverflow quando eu dou um System.out.println(lista.get(0).getAditivo()); q é pra eu ver a lista de aditivos q ele me retornaria

Comment: Tenta tirar o @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)  pra fazer um teste

Comment: mesmo erro tirando o fetch, mas é algum erro no tostring mesmo, fiz o teste e dá erro qdo executo System.out.println(lista.get(0).getAditivo().get(0)); --- mas se eu der um lista.get(0).getAditivo().size() ele retorna certinho o tamanho do array, e se eu der um lista.get(0).getAditivo().get(0).getId() ele me traz a id do aditivo corretamente, é só na hora de exibir todo o array

Comment: Se você só usar `System.out.println(lista.get(0).getAditivo().getId())` da erro?

Comment: sim dá o mesmo erro, ele não consegue escrever o tostring, só direto a variavel

Comment: Direto a variável dá certo?

Comment: sim, se eu der um lista.get(0).getAditivo().get(0).getId()  ele traz a id do primeiro aditivo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48272/discussion-between-diegoaugusto-and-adriano).

Comment: coloquei uma resposta que resolve seu problema. Veja se te atende.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro `StackOverflowError` acontece pois você está entrando em um loop infinito. Pense comigo, você quer exibir os aditivos, porém dentro de aditivo você tem um contrato que por sua vez também tem uma lista de aditivos, ou seja sempre vai ficar nesse ciclo até dar um `StackOverflow`.

Uma solução é sobrescrever o seu método `toString()` para que só alguns dados sejam exibidos. Exemplo:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Aditivo [id=" + id + ", numero=" + numero + ", contrato="
            + contrato.getNumero() + "]";
}
```

Repare que ao invés de pegar o contrato inteiro estou pegando apenas seu numero.

Comment: exatamente funcionou obrigado caro vc é o máximo, no contrato eu tirei o aditivo do to string e quando precisar eu dou um getcontrato.getaditivo funcionou aqui, desse jeito q vc falou tb funciona obrigado mesmo, tava em loop infinito

Comment: Sim, de ambas as formas funciona. Por nada e bons estudos.

Answer (score 1):

Não use isso

> @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)

porque precisa usar dessa forma? **remova isso e resolve.**

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Aditivo.class, mappedBy="contrato", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL })
private List<Aditivo> aditivo;
```

Se tiver duas coleções no mesmo objeto não podem ser as duas **FetchType.EAGER**
Se só usar especificação JPA o @Cascade, remova-o

Outro problema.

**Esta nesse bloco de código**

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Contratos [id=" + id + ", aditivo=" + aditivo + ", numero="
            + numero + "]";
}
```

Faça o devido tratamento... ele esta gerando erro ai também..
use **aditivo.toString()** ou algo assim, para resolver conforme seu cenário

Comment: já tirei e continua o mesmo, postei ali em cima um comentário, ele nao dá erro se dou um size, mas nao hora de dar um get ele dá erro

Comment: Atualizei a reposta,

Comment: Se não resolver posta ai, que dois mais dicas

Comment: nao resolveu assim, continuou o mesmo erro

Comment: Atualizei a resposta